# Encoding of constant string values differ on mac and on linux

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dotnet project where the end result is an excel file created and returned to the requester. Project built on Mac but deployed on Linux. The labels used in the column headers of the excel file are dynamic and values are looked up in a dictionary. Problem is that the resulting excel file when created on the linux server scrambles the characters. it works fine in the development environment on my mac.

Code example

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ExportFields()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "e.id", "ID" },
        { "e.event", "Händelser" },
        { "e.door", "Dörrar" },
    };
}
```

Result on Linux: HÃ¤ndelser, DÃ¶rrar
Result on Mac: Händelser, Dörrar

Any data fetched from the Mysql database are shown fine in the excel file regardless of platform.
Deployoment is done by simply selecting Publish to folder for the project in question and then distributing the resulting files.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The faulty label strings are doing round-trip to Mysql to form part of the query. Query will look like SELECT e.event AS `Händelser` /.../. Perhaps this is where the mangling occurs.

Hopefully relevant code snippets:

Preparing the query

```
List<String> strSelect = new List<String>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in ExportFields)
{
    strSelect.Add($"{item.Key} AS `{item.Value}`");
}
var _query = string.Format(query, String.Join(", ", strSelect), strJoin, strWhere, (queryParams.limit.Length > 0 ? $"LIMIT {EncodeSQL(queryParams.limit)}" : ""), (extraQueryParam.Length > 0 ? extraQueryParam : null));
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(_query, conn);
MySqlDataAdapter mAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
mAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
mAdapter.Fill(dSet);
```

Snippet from the create excel section populating the header row

```
Row headerRow = new Row() { RowIndex = 1 };
for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < table.Columns.Count; iColumn++)
{
var col = table.Columns[iColumn];
    headerRow.Append(new Cell
    {
        DataType = CellValues.String,
        CellValue = new CellValue(Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][col]))
    });
}
allRows.Add(headerRow);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=net-5.0) so default culture isn't changing the characters when they're being read?

Comment: Just to note -- the problem not in the encoding of the constant string, the problem will be somewhere around when the excel file is written, but you haven't included that code so it's hard to spot issues

Comment: Are you saving the Excel file with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: the issue will be in the encoding of the file, can you specify which library are you using or can you put your code if you are doing it manually

Comment: The specific problem of `ö` being mis-rendered as `Ã¶` comes from the `ö` being written as UTF-8 bytes, and then incorrectly interpreted as if it was `ISO 8859-1`. So somewhere along the way, you've got a tool which is reading a UTF-8-encoded file, and interpreting those bytes as ISO 8859-1. The simplest explanation is the tool used to view the Excel file (assuming it's actually CSV) is getting it wrong: if it's an actual xlsx read by Excel, something else in the pipeline must be getting it wrong

Comment: [The default encoding is UTF8 on .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0), try using Unicode for reading and writing prospectively.

Comment: ... but that's all we can say based on the little information you've given I'm afraid. We really need a [mcve] to take this further. If you've got more information please [edit] it into your question, otherwise this will probably be closed as lacking sufficient detail

Comment: It would also be good to know what runtime you're using. Are you using mono perhaps, or .NET Core? That matters.

Comment: Wow, love the responsiveness of this community! So answers to questions where possible. It's .NET Core. The end result is a real excel file displayed in Excel. Created by using DocumentFormat.OpenXml. Server runs on Linux 7.X. However, if relevant, the label strings are passed on to Mysql as part of the query. I will try to edit all relevant code into my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is something with the connection between dotnet and mysql.

My solution was to URL encode the labels when inserting them into the query and decode the reply.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in ExportFields)
{
     strSelect.Add($"{item.Key} AS '{WebUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value).ToString()}'");
}
```

in the reply

```
headerRow.Append(new Cell
{
     DataType = CellValues.String,
     CellValue = new CellValue(WebUtility.UrlDecode(col.ColumnName))
});
```

There can be other, better, solutions but this works. Moving on.